# Gaseous reactant in Nernst equation

Tags: electrochemistry, nernst-equation

So I have this equation of a galvanic cell

> $\ce{Zn + Cl2 -> Zn^{2+} + 2Cl^-}$

Why does the Nernst equation not consider pressure of $\ce{Cl2}$ here? Only concentrations of zinc and chloride ions are being considered in my textbook.

Am new on SE, so am really sorry for any errors.

Comment: A asking B why C has written something wrong or incomplete is a bad concept. // The N. eq. does involve partial pressure on involved redox-active gas, but the writers of textbooks must mention it. You should always refer to the source of questioned info for others to know what is rather to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

The Nernst equation does involve partial pressure on involved redox-active gas, but the writers of textbooks must mention it. You should always refer to the source of questioned info for others to know what is rather to be avoided.

As exampple, the Nernst equation for the non-standard hydrogen electrode is

$$E = E^° + \frac{RT}{2F} \ln{\frac{a(\ce{H+})^2}{p(\ce{H2})}}$$

Another thing is, that the particular formulation may use implied default gas pressure, not being explicitly expressed in the equation.